# NullPointerException while getting data via another class from firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, nullpointerexception

I created a class called `UserInfo` to get all user data from firebase database. Here is the method I used to get firebase data (username).

```
 public String getUsername() {
        final Firebase usernameLink = new Firebase(firebaseLink + getUid());
        usernameLink.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                username = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            }
        });
        return username;
    }
```

And the firebase link has no problem. And it gives the username too.

But in another class I want to get the username.

So I made a object of that class..

```
UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
```

And to get the username,

```
username = userInfo.getUsername();
```

I wrote the previous code in my `onCreate` method.

On a button click in my app, I am trying to add the username as my child.

```
send_request_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                request_text = request_msg.getText().toString();
                URL = new Firebase(firebaseUrl);
               Firebase addChild = URL.child(username);
                                addChild.setValue("hhhhh");        
                        }
                );
```

Well this code works when I replace username with some dummy predefined string data. But when I add username it gives me the following error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
 at com.firebase.client.Firebase.child(Firebase.java:187)
 at com.buckydroid.anonchat.SendRequest$1$1.onClick(SendRequest.java:67)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Please have patience  --- you just asked this question not 25 minutes ago! Also which line throws the NPE, and which variable is null?

Comment: username is throwing NPE and sorry @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: The line is Firebase addChild = NotificationURL.child(userInfo.getUsername());

Comment: Then username is absolutely **not** the variable causing the NPE to be thown. Perhaps it's userInfo, or NotificationURL -- did you test which is null? If not, you will want to do so.

Comment: As I said, After changing NotificationURL.child(username); to NotificationURL.child("username"); or some other dummy value everything works correctly

Comment: The user name is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. By the time your `return` statement runs, it hasn't been loaded yet. Instead of explaining this again, I'll refer to an answer I wrote earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918459/firebase-android-fetchprovidersforemail-why-are-all-the-calls-asynchronous/41918701#41918701

Comment: Can u plz give a little hint here on what should I do? I am little confused @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your variable firebaseLink is initialized and is assigned to some data before running this method.  The NullPointerException output I'm seeing tells me that you are trying to pass a null variable to the pathString variable of the Firebase class.

Comment: firebaseLink is correct. As I said when I replace username variable with some dummy string, It works .

Comment: Try casting the variable to a (String) when passing it to child(var) then.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the user me variable is being initialized to begin with? Do a system.out.println(username) right before calling firebase.child() and see if it prints null

Comment: Yeah username is null

Comment: Boom. Move back farther in your code and try to find out why username isn't being initialized then try it again

Comment: I tried System.out.println in UserInfo class and it's working

Comment: Are you declaring the username variable inside the oncreate method?

Comment: I declared username variable before onCreate and associated userinfo.getUsername(); to username variable inside onCreate

Comment: Is there a constructor other than default in the user info class? You may need to pass it information when declaring your userinfo variable to initialize everything properly